# How to get or copy Office settings from another workbook?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, add-in, excel-addins

I am developing an Excel add-in and storing workbook & add-in details in the Office settings to get the workbook settings whenever I share a workbook with someone. I have followed [this steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.settings?view=common-js-preview) to implement functionality.

Now I want to copy these settings from one workbook to another workbook using Office JS Excel add-in. Could you please guide me on how to implement this functionality or tell me that is it possible or not?

Comment: Theoretically one can copy the file and replace the data, so should be possible.  Whether its possible when constrained to a specific add in might be another matter though.

Comment: Can you please justify your words? Is this possible or not? if possible then please share any documents for that. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done in an Excel add-in. With a few very limited exceptions, an add-in is in a world where there is only one workbook; the one that is currently open. It can read and write the open workbook, but it cannot reach out to some other workbook and write to it.

Comment: If you have a backend, then the state can be shared